# Display outline on all unselected radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I want to display an outline to all radio buttons which are not selected by the user.

Currently I have 4 pairs of radio button, it may increase later. I have given the code for the individual radio button selection which is working but looking for a code to dynamically test all radio buttons which is inside the div and then highlight all radio buttons those are not selected by the user.

Code:
Jquery:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#BtnContinue").click(function(){

if (!$('input[name="radio1"]').is(':checked')) {
        $('input[name="radio1"]').css("outline","2px solid red");

}   

if (!$('input[name="direc"]').is(':checked')) {
        $('input[name="direc"]').css("outline","2px solid red");

}


});

});
```

HTML:

```
<input class="userChoice radio" type="radio" name="radio1" value="direnquiryonly">

<input class="userChoice radio" type="radio" name="direc" value="phonebookwithdirenquiry">

<input class="userChoice radio" type="radio" name="direc" value="direnquiryonly">
</div>
```

etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#BtnContinue").click(function() {
    updateOutlines();
  });

  $('input:radio').click(updateOutlines);
});

function updateOutlines() {
  $('input:radio').css('outline', 'none');
  $('input:radio').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked') && !$('input:radio[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').is(":checked")) {
      $(this).css("outline", "2px solid red");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="userChoice radio" type="radio" name="radio1" value="direnquiryonly">

<input class="userChoice radio" type="radio" name="direc" value="phonebookwithdirenquiry">

<input class="userChoice radio" type="radio" name="direc" value="direnquiryonly">

<button id='BtnContinue'>continue</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there is a minor issue. When I select a radio button after displaying outline, the outline is not removing.

Comment: It is removing after clicking the continue button, but I'm expecting the outline to hide as soon as user selects the radio.

Comment: From your question, we understand, you have a button with id `BtnContinue` and on click on that outline will appear or disappear.

Comment: Correct, but also need a functionality to hide the outline once the radio button is selected. Firstly, click on submit without selecting any radio, then select any radio, then the outline should be disabled from the selected radio.

Comment: @user3774781 - Alright, that's been taken care too.

Comment: There is an issue in this code, after refreshing the page and then selecting any radio button, then the unselected radio is highlighting before selecting Continue button

Answer (score 2):

Why do this in code?  You could solve this with one line of CSS, with no need for either if branch.

```
input { outline: 2px solid red; }
input:checked { outline: none; }
```

Or, even simpler:

```
input:not(:checked) { outline: 2px solid red; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').css("outline", "none");
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).css("outline", "2px solid red");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there is a minor issue. When I select a radio button after displaying outline, the outline is not removing which means after page load only it's working

Comment: @user3774781 please see my updated answer. If you've used the answer please mark it as correct in order to help others.

Comment: I tried with this code. But it is not removing the outline after selection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select your input by **"type"** use the **$(this)** selector :

```
if (!$('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).css("outline","2px solid red");
```